# What value is expanded in an indirect expansion?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

In the manual page for bash, the indirect expansion for a parameter that is not a nameref is explained as

> If the first character of parameter is  an  exclamation  point (!),  and parameter is not a nameref, it introduces a level of indirection.  Bash uses the value formed by expanding the rest of  parameter  as the new parameter; this is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the expansion,  rather  than the expansion of the original parameter.  This is known as indirect expansion.  **The value is subject  to  tilde  expansion, parameter  expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion.**

But I am not able to replicate the last sentence.

Setting `x=y`, `y=z` and `z=end`. The result is as expected.

```
$ echo ${!x}
z
```

Setting `x=y`, `y='$z'` and `z=end`.

```
$ echo ${!x}
$z
```

Setting `x='$y'`, `y=z`, and `z=end`.

```
$ echo ${!x}
-bash: $y: invalid variable name
```

So, what value is subject of expansions as mentioned above in the documentation? What am I missing?

(Bash version used is 5.1.0(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)).

Comment: The part where it says _"Bash uses the value formed by expanding the rest of parameter as the new parameter; this is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the expansion"_ also sounds a bit odd.  It made me try something like `"${!$foo}"`, but that also gives "bad substitution". (Maybe for the better.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like a documentation bug. The [commit that introduced that text](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/commit/?id=2e4125745321da8cea9cd814173393d22cb74c60) goes rather in the opposite direction:

Quoting the related additions to `CWRU/CWRU.log` in the source distribution:

```
+                                  12/18
+                                  -----
+subst.c
+       - parameter_brace_find_indir: when expanding the indirect parameter
+         to find the eventual variable name, we don't perform word splitting.
+         Make sure this does the right thing for * and @.  Fixes bug
+         reported by isabella parakiss <izaberina@gmail.com>
+
+                                  12/19
+                                  -----
+doc/{bash.1,bashref.texi}
+       - indirect expansion: make sure to note that the value of the indirect
+         variable does not undergo word splitting as one of its expansions,
+         as in fix from 12/18
```

That text is probably missing a *not*: *The value is **not** subject...*.